# ngFor removing duplicates in observable list

Tags: angular

I want to remove duplicates values in observable list. Only in template, not changing component!

Using the index I want removing duplicates values in double *ngFor.

Is there any way?

```
<div class="order-list-row" *ngFor="let list of sandbox.orderList$ | async;">
    <div class="olr-header flex">
        <div class="olrh-lft flex">
            <div class="olrh-lft-col">
                <h5>주문코드</h5>
                <p>{{list.orderPrefixId}}</p>
```

I want to skip the values(list.orderPrefixId) ​​that have already been printed by applying a condition(using index)

Comment: use pipe for filtering items or look into rxjs pipe funcs for filtering values

Comment: template cant filter anything

Answer (score 1):

You could use a directive or better still logic like this are meant to stay in your component file. Doing this kind of Filtering in your template file is a bad design it self.

Subscribe to the observable in your component file and perform your filtering therein

Answer (score 1):

I realize you asked for a solution in the template, but I will give you 2 sensible solutions. One of which isn't really in the template, but it preserves the original observable just as well:

```js
obs$: Observable<number[]> = of([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]);

filteredObs$ = this.obs$.pipe(
  map((arr) => {
    return new Set(arr);
  })
);
```

In template:

```html
<p *ngFor="let n of filteredObs$ | async">
  {{ n }}
</p>
```

If you want the filtering to happen **in the template**, you can create a function:

```js
filterArray(arr: number[]): number[] {
  return Array.from(new Set(arr));
}
```

In template:

```html
<p *ngFor="let n of filterArray(obs$! | async)">
  {{ n }}
</p>
```

*I just used a number[] in this example but the idea is the same for objects, the mapping would just be a little more complex. There are plenty examples for that on the net, but if you need help with that just ask.*

Here's my example in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k1cmaz?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

Really the best approach is create a new observable with the uniques values

if your `sandbox.orderList$` return, e.g. some like

```
[{id:0},{id:1},{id:2},{id:2},{id:3},{id:0},...]
```

You can define

```
orderListUnique$=this.sandbox.orderList$.pipe(
     map((res:any[],i:number)=>
          res.reduce((a,b)=>a.find(x=>x.id==b.id)?a:[...a,b],[])
  ))
```

And use `orderListUnique$ |async`

**only for fun**

If your list is ordered you can write some "bizarro" like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ values: values$ | async } as values">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let value of values.values; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="i == 0 ? null : '' + values.values[i - 1].id as old">
      <p *ngIf="value.id != old">
        {{ value.id }}
      </p>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

If your list is not ordered, you need to have an array with the key to order, e.g. if you has a variable "indexValues"

```
obs$=observable.pipe(
    tap((res:any[])=>this.indexValues=res.map(x=>x.id)))
```

And use

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let value of objValues$ | async; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="indexValues.indexOf(value.id) == i">
    <p>
      {{ value.id }}
    </p>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

You can see the approach in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eko57h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)